# Can we have more "developer types" please?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm an embedded systems/low-level programming/drivers/kernel sort of guy, and I don't see anything in the "developer types" list that matches me at all... can we please have some more options? I'm sure there are other people who don't fit in those slots too well...

Comment: I think it will be appropriate for SE to have jobs for SF and DBA also. Imagine the poor DB Admins.

Comment: Taking a look at what all will have to change before we make a decision, will get back to you asap.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'm also interested in how the current list came to be... it seems very heavily weighted to high-level technologies.

Comment: @NickLarsen shouldn't this be marked [tag:status-review] then?

Comment: @RamenChef No, [status-review] is generally not used for anything (or at least that was the case back when I worked at Stack Overflow). The presence of a [status-*] takes it out of the default bug-tracking view, so that tag would only be used (IMHO) if it's something that won't be touched in a long time and its presence would clutter up the view.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like we'll be able to make some changes here but I'll leave the status change up to the PM (@Des) in charge.

As for why it's the way it is...

That section of your profile is used for targeting jobs to you on the jobs homepage when the sort by is set to `matches`.  When that page was designed it was limited to the same list that we allow jobs to specifically target, and that's that.

So why is that the only things we allow jobs to target?  That's all the roles we're confident in claiming we're better than random matching on.  That model was built a couple years ago and despite some interesting ideas and valiant attempts, we had been unable to beat it until very recently.  The truth is that the vast majority of our jobs fit into those roles we have listed (with the notable exception of QA jobs which we also have not figured out) and we just didn't have enough data on other job roles to be able to effectively target them.

The main dilemma is this: do we show roles we cannot effectively target and risk the product feeling broken when no one applies or do we risk the product feeling broken when the role they want to hire for isn't in the targetable list?  It's a hard decision with lots of good arguments on both sides and so far we've favored restricting the options to things we're confident we should be able to target well (read that as better than random).  The hope is to set expectations for our customers and our sales team's sanity.  This let's us address concerns very directly when one of our sales team comes to saying that their client thinks the product is broken after making a perfectly valid selection.  "Well, they are probably right, let me see if we can figure out why" instead of "yea, that button doesn't actually do anything".  We have preferred to address that concern up front.

So why are we considering this change on the developer side?  A couple reasons, naively in hopes of some better labeled data to work with, and more importantly that it's less broken on the dev profile side.

The majority of devs using the site don't have profiles, and usually they are not even logged in.  The profiles as they work for matching are largely influenced by the actual questions you are viewing (other factors like geo as well).  We expand this to try to guess what you're good at, but all we have are question views.  Not very many questions have random job roles in them.

On the other hand, pretty much every job has the role listed in it.  If you want to type in a role we don't have listed we think we'll gain some valuable information from that which might eventually help us do targeting better, and we can still serve you in the meantime via full text search instead of just feature matching. (shout out to @Des for that idea)

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 6):

This is a good suggestion, thanks. I'm marking this as status-deferred until we get it scheduled. Then, I'll update it to status-planned.